# Changing username (the one with the at sign) on Twitter

Tags: twitter

How can I change my @ name on Twitter? I don't care about losing followers as I don't have any.

I can see how to change my "name", but my @ name isn't changing when I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your @ username via the [Account Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account) page. (Changing your person name is done via the [Profile Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/profile) page).

The **Username** field is where your @ name is set. Changing it here will update your account to a new location. As you type, it will show you if the new username has already been taken or if it's availabe to use.

For example, if you updated your username to `monkeyillusions` then your new Twitter page URL would be: `https://twitter.com/monkeyillusions`.

Note: Any previous replies or mentions of your old username will not be updated.